# C Program crashing with large arrays

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I'm trying to run a simulation that involves a large amount of calculations and values.

I've got an issue in that large arrays cause the program to crash before it's even declared any variables. I'm not sure if this is due to my code or due to my operating system refusing to run the program.

Code that crashes the program is:

```
long double adsorption[2][4][5][10001]
```

This array should use about 10^6 bytes, and SIZE_MAX is 10^19, so I'm confused as to why it's crashing. (Program is 64 bit in Task Manager)

I'm running on Windows 7 64bit with 12 Gb of memory, of which 10 Gb is generally free. Compiler is MinGW-w64

Apologies if this is quite basic, I'm from a physics background, not coding!

Cheers

Comment: Stacks (on which most compilers put their local variables on) have usually a single-digit number of megabytes available. On Windows, for example, it's usually one a single megabyte, while your array of arrays etc. is at least 4 million bytes (almost 4 MB) if `long double` is 80 bits, well over 6 MB if `long double` is 128 bits.

Comment: If you declare this as a local variable then it will typically be allocated on the stack, which is of limited size, and so you get a *stack overflow*.

Comment: Can you explain why you an array with this many dimensions, perhaps we can offer a better alternative. The current answer mentions `malloc`, but it is likely that a 2 x 4 x 5 x 10001 array is not the best approach. And `long double`? I don't think there ever was a need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adsorption` is being allocated on the *stack*, and it must be overflowing the stack. Hence the error.

Use `malloc` and family to allocate large chunks of data on the *heap*.

**edit**

Or make it static -- @Matt McNabb thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a stack overflow.

Bearing in mind that;

```
1 byte =    n bits
1 kb   = 1024 bytes = 2^10 bytes
1 mb   = 1024 kb    = 2^20 bytes
1 gb   = 1024 mb    = 2^30 bytes
1 tb   = 1024 gb    = 2^40 bytes
```

Assuming the default stack sizes in gcc are (*according to [this webpage](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt)*);

- **Linux**:   `1.8MB` | `1,872KB` | `1,916,928 bytes`
- **Windows**: `1MB` | `1,024KB` | `1,048,576 bytes`

---

Expanding on `rohit`'s answer (*originally i was just going to write a comment, but it's to much writing for a comment and i have a solution at the end*), if your array has `3,200,320 bytes` | `3,125KB` | `3MB`

the size of your stack overflow on each platform would be;

- **Linux**: `3,125KB - 1,872KB = 1,253KB` | `1,283,072 bytes` overflowed.
- **Windows**: `3,125KB - 1,024KB = 2,101KB` | `2,151,424 bytes` overflowed.

---

To make gcc compile your program with a larger stack, like 8MB you can do;

```
gcc file.c -Wl,--stack,8388608
```

And the program should not overflow because after the array is put on the stack you are left with:

- `8,388,608 - 3,200,320 = 5,188,288 bytes` | `5,066KB` | `4.9MB` of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables implicitely have *automatic storage duration*, so they are effectively placed in space-limited stack. Either declare you array with `static` qualifier, move it into global scope, outside any function (so now implicitely it has *static storage duration*, which variables are placed on data segment, note `static` in this context means something totally different, so don't be "explicit to much" there), or use `malloc` or `calloc` functions from `<stdlib.h>` header to allocate it on heap (especially useful if size of array indices is known run-time).

Note that C99 also features variable-length arrays (VLA), where size of indices is determined run-time, however these are only limited to automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

2*4*5*10001 = **400,040 elements**.
Double means **8 bytes per element**.
And 400,040 * 8 = **3,200,320 bytes**

3,200,320 bytes size is beyond the stack memory size to handle.